# Magento 1.9.3.6 Item (Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule) with the same id "192" already exist

Tags: magento-1.9.3.6

```
Item (Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule) with the same id "192" already exist
Trace:
#0 /home/site/web/website.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(582): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))

     public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        if ($this->isLoaded()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->_beforeLoad();

        $this->_renderFilters()
             ->_renderOrders()
             ->_renderLimit();

        $this->printLogQuery($printQuery, $logQuery);
        $data = $this->getData();
        $this->resetData();

        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $item = $this->getNewEmptyItem();
                if ($this->getIdFieldName()) {
                    $item->setIdFieldName($this->getIdFieldName());
                }
                $item->addData($row);
                $this->addItem($item);
            }
        }

        $this->_setIsLoaded();
        $this->_afterLoad();
        return $this;
    }

#1 /home/site/web/website.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()

    public function getIterator()
    {
        $this->load();
        return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
    }
```

This error working after click product on list for view detail
[image]

Comment: check your collection query.your query get duplicate entry in result due to join

Comment: Please check : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19562/item-mage-salesrule-model-rule-with-the-same-id-5-already-exist

Comment: Thx, i'm use one backend for 2 website. 1st website no problem but 2nd website have problem 1st : lifeford.com 2nd : dcashpro.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you added something in your collection, which adds duplicates to the query result.

so check your collection, if they have ambiguous join then remove that join or make other model as parent model and join other

Comment: Thx, i'm use one backend for 2 website.
1st website no problem but 2nd website have problem
1st : https://www.lifeford.com/
2nd : https://www.dcashpro.com/